# Need to redirect all files/folders under subfolder but leave subfolder alone

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I hope my title makes sense. Here is what I have: On our previous website, we had URLs similar to the following:

www.example.com/support/BIOS/JXT/0ABWDA22.zip

This same file on our new site has the structure:

www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/support/BIOS/JXT/0ABWDA22.zip

However our new site also has a page located at:

www.example.com/support

so I cannot use something like ^/support/(.*) as it rewrites and breaks the main support page. I am looking for any suggestions. I thought that perhaps the easiest way to handle this would be to ONLY rewrite urls where there is a file extension present? I have been googling for this very thing but haven't really stumbled across a solution as of yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for file-extension based redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.(zip|jpg|png))$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]
```

not sure of the correct syntax with folders, but in theory this should work...

Comment: Thank you! I had to modify it just a bit but it seems to do exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

how is actual rule for  www.example.com/support  ?
i would suggest to create a rule that only apply to that URL [and redirects to the very same page], add a [L] command flag and THEN insert the ^/support/(.*)  statement